# R function merging date data into one column

Tags: r

I'm still getting my head around R so please excuse my ignorance. I currently have a dataset with several columns of different dates:

```
       Country.Region X2020.01.22 X2020.01.23 X2020.01.24
1         Afghanistan           0           0           0
2             Algeria           0           0           0
3             Andorra           0           0           0
4              Angola           0           0           0
5 Antigua and Barbuda           0           0           0
6           Argentina           0           0           0
  X2020.01.25 X2020.01.26 X2020.01.27 X2020.01.28 X2020.01.29
1           0           0           0           0           0
2           0           0           0           0           0
3           0           0           0           0           0
4           0           0           0           0           0
5           0           0           0           0           0
6           0           0           0           0           0
```

I am trying to tidy the data to gather all the date columns into one and give the "recovered" value in another separate column. Any suggestions on what function I should use? That would also allow me to convert the date column from a character format to a date format.

Any help I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: Use `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr`: `pivot_longer(mydf, starts_with("X"), names_to = "date", values_to = "recovered")`

Comment: Thanks Phil for your reply, I ran your suggestion but received this error ```Error: unused arguments (names_to = "date", values_to = "recovered")```

Comment: I can't help you without knowing what you ran.

Comment: ```pivot_longer(RECOVERED, starts_with("County.Region"), names_to = "date", values_to = "recovered")```

Comment: You didn't run my suggestion. I said `starts_with("X")`

Comment: Oh my apologies that worked. Thanks I really appreciate it!